# Rails validation - inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to add a validation to prevent the user from entering a url that does not include the word 'mywebsite' in it.

```
validates :url, inclusion: { in: %w(mywebsite), message: "Must be a mywebsite.com subdomain" }
```

The problem with the above code is that it will only accept 'mywebsite' as a valid argument, while I'd like it to accept any argument which includes the word mywebsite in it.  Example: mywebsite.com/something

How should I approach this?

Comment: You probably need to use regex. %r instead of %w

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: I'm new to regex, but wouldn't it do the same thing, i.e. only approve an exact match?

Comment: You can write it that way, of course. But you can write it so it suits your needs.

Comment: Check the regular expression examples, you will find what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the guidance.  Here is a working solution to my question:

```
validates_format_of :url, :with => /mywbesite(.*)/
```